# Is "local our" the thing to use in object modules under mod_perl2, or only in scripts?

Tags: perl, oop, module, mod-perl2

To tailor your scripts toward mp2, avoiding the need for any compatibility wrappers and such, it's said that you're supposed to declare variables using "local our" rather than "my".  What about in modules?

```
sub new
{
    local our $type = shift;
    local our $self = {};
    bless $self, $type;
}
```

Is that right?  Or should it be 'my' so the rest of the module can get at $self under "use strict"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need `my`.

The `local our` advice pertains to variables that are global in your module.

Comment: So all along, the moral of the story should've been, globals are evil?

Answer (score 5):

`local our` is an ugly construct that will bite you in the long run.

See the [thread](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=574597) on Perlmonks for more details.

Comment: I couldn't fully grasp the discussion that followed; however, the guide still does include it two years later, so perhaps he didn't win the discussion list argument?

Comment: As it turns out, even Stas Bekman agrees ( http://www.nabble.com/local-our-td6489165.html )...I wonder why the docs were never updated after all that?  :|

Comment: That's a very good question. I know that I have seen threads about it on the various lists...

Answer (score 0):

Also $self is obtained in methods as $_[0] (Perl automatically prepends @_ with it.)

Comment: Add this to the question. Then remove this "Answer".

Comment: It's an answer to 'Or should it be 'my' so the rest of the module can get at $self under "use strict"?' that I discovered after asking.

Comment: Please, don't use $_[0]. I recommend never doing that, but there may be exceptions. Don't use it for the sake of mod_perl anyway.

Comment: I just meant it was the first element.  You could use shift.  But, I'm curious, why do you say that?  Isn't it more efficient than shift?  You haven't said what downside motivates your recommendation.

Comment: Oh. I thought that was obvious: 1. It's ugly. very ugly. 2. It's hard to type. 3. It's hard to read (is this a method and is $_[0] thus self? Or is this something else entirely). 4. It may trigger strange little bugs when another method changes @_.